# What does it mean for a flour to be "strong" or "reinforced"?

Tags: baking, bread, flour, pizza

When describing flour, I sometimes see people comparing flours and saying that one is *strong* or *stronger than another*.

I also see flours that claim to be *reinforced* such as the *Antimo Caputo 00 Rinforzato*, where Rinforzato = Reinforced.

I had my own idea of what it meant, thinking it had something to do with higher gluten content, but right now, I'm not sure if that is correct.

Comment: I've always understood 'strong flour' to mean bread flour ... something that'll develop good gluten, unlike a 'soft' flour (pastry or cake flour).  I've never heard of 'reinforced' flour.

Comment: Although, now that I think about it ... there's 'vital wheat gluten' .. maybe it's flour that has extra gluten mixed in?

Comment: The two aren't necessarily the same thing; "strong" is used in many places and while "rinforzato" seems to be associated specifically with that brand of flour.

Comment: I  believe a straight translation of rinforzato from Italian yields "reinforced". Of course, something that is reinforced can be thought of as "strong". I agree that it's possible that they are not necessarily the same thing, but then again, it may be.

Answer (score 2):

Strong flour does mean higher gluten flour. I can't really find much info out about the Rinforzato flour. My guess would be that that could mean "enriched" but since another question ([Red and blue Antimo Caputo 00 flour](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/41610/red-and-blue-antimo-caputo-00-flour)) seems to indicate that it has higher protein, it may just have some added vital wheat gluten to make it stronger.

Comment: The bag says "Ingredients: Soft White Wheat". It does not indicate any other ingredients. Enriched means that nutrients are added back in (vitamins and minerals) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enriched_flour.

The ingredient list does not indicate that Vital Wheat Gluten is added into the flour, but certain strains of soft white white with higher gluten content could be used in the Rinforzato.